# Vector does not accept new element properly

Tags: c++

I see some odd behaviour in the code below. My console is printing

> 0lo1lo

when in reality I am expecting

> 0Hel1lo

Node.cpp

```
std::vector<Node> Node::getChildren() {
    return children;
}

void Node::setChildren(std::vector<Node> childrenNodes) {
    children = childrenNodes;
}

void Node::addChild(Node child) {
    children.push_back(child);
    std::cout << child.getTitle();
}

std::string Node::getTitle() {
    return title;
}
```

From Main function

```
Node root = Node("root");
root.addChild(Node("Hel"));
root.addChild(Node("lo"));
std::cout << "\n";
std::vector<Node> children = root.getChildren();
for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
    Node menuItem = children[i];
    std::cout << i;
    std::cout << menuItem.getTitle();
}
std::cout << "\n";
```

Does anybody have an idea why getChildren() appears to be getting a vector that is not accurately listing the first element I inserted?

Comment: Have you heard of const and references - makes the code have better performance. Also default values and initialisation lists.

Comment: Usually private variables, especially though's available to the entirety of the cpp are declared in the header. Also there's so much copying going on here, you really should look into ret by ref and ret by const ref. And i'm not really sure where you're going with having separate One parent and many nodes per container, but it doesn't seem overly practical.

Comment: its a console interface where each menu consists of a range of options, and each of those can consist of additional options, etc.. Root acts as the starting point. I'd be open to any suggestions of alternative data structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using global variables to store instance data:

```
std::string title;
```

That means there's only one `title` in your program and if you ever change it, it changes for every class, function, etc. that accesses it.

Make it a non-static member variable of `Node` and your problem will go away.

Comment: I would accept your answer now but it tells me to wait 12 minutes, I guess this was an easy one :P